# Understanding protein-peptide docking analysis

Tags: docking

I want to explore some potential reactive peptides and seems a common step to conduct some form of docking analysis. I have a question about the theory and a practical question.

**Practical question:**

An interesting secondary step seems to be to calculate the binding energy with something like [PRODIGY](https://wenmr.science.uu.nl/prodigy/), although I'm struggling to understand the .pdb files to run the webserver.

Once I have created a .pdb on either HPEPDOCK or CABS-dock, how do I find the naming convention for the peptides ( Ligand ID ) within the .pdb file? So that I can run in Prodigy-Ligand.

**Theory question:**

I'm struggling to understand what to take-away from the docking analysis.

I've been using HPEPDOCK ( & CABS-dock, although the former is significantly quicker and seems a good starting place ).

I've been trying to read some papers and see how they use docking analysis. I get the feeling, particularly for peptide-protein ( known receptor ), it is simply a visual inspection to see if it makes sense. Adding the abstract docking score to double check it is low enough ( < -100 ).

[image]

I'm struggling to understand further use - most papers seem to simply state they did such analysis and ~ it looked okay, or ~ chose the good ones.

If anyone can recommend some literature that might help me understand, that would be great!

Comment: 'Reactive peptides' (covalent peptidomimetics) are generally far from a medchemist's first choice.
A `ligand` is not a peptide, it is a small molecule. A residue in compbiochem is a unit and can be AAs residues, NCAAs residues, ligands or ions. Caffeine has the residue name/id `CFF`. Therefore, you need to use the first tab: protein-protein.